# Viewing messages being sent over ALPC Port?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, rpc, inter-process-communicat

I am trying to figure out the messages being used on a specific ALPC port in Windows 7, and since it doesn't seem like there is any place where the ports messages are documented only the actual ports themselves, I would like to listen in to certain ports an view the messages being sent to the port.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Have you tried kernel logging with the [ALPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964738(v=vs.85).aspx) class?

Comment: That is what I am going to do. It seems to be the only way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ALPC calls are intended to be fast, so there's not a lot of interception points.  Your best bets are:

1. Enable ETW kernel logging and monitor the message flows with the [ALPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class (strongly recommended)
2. Hack around with the [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) library.  I don't recommend this, as it's a global solution, and doesn't let you look at specific ports.  If you need to *deploy* the solution, it's even worse.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I am going with your first recommendation.